# etc/hosts entry always opened as https

Tags: localhost, wsl-2, hosts, hosts-file

I am using WSL2 with Windows 11 with Ubuntu

Currently I have a app running on localhost and I want to be able to access it on `app.local` (e.g.).

I have added an entry

`127.0.0.1 app.local`

Inside of my hosts file on Windows & inside of my Linux distrubution.
From here on it get's weird when I ping app.local everything works as expected and I receive a few responses.

When I want to access my application now in the Browser (Firefox & Edge) it redirects me to https://app.... and responds with "page is not secure" which makes sense because I do not have any SSL cerificates set.

How can I get rid of the behaviour that I always get redirected to https

Comment: Are you sure there is a service running on port 80 of 127.0.0.1 ? I usually see that behaviour if no service is reachable with http, then browsers automatically try https.

Comment: my service is running under port 8080, is that a problem ?

Comment: I just realised that I made a stupid mistake.. 
I set the host to app.local on Ubunntu but local.app on Windows :(

Comment: different port is not a problem but you have to append it to the URL. also different host names for Windows and Linux in the /etc/hosts file are not a problem as long as you tell your web server that it should accept requests for the hostname that windows uses.